# Android imageview setBackgroundResources() according to the current background

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to change the background of an imageview after clicking on a button according to the current background 
but can't figure out what the if statement should look like

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

ImageButton next=(ImageButton)findViewbuId(R.id.imageButton1);
final ImageView pages = (ImageView)findById(R.id.imageView1);

next.setOnClickListener(new View.onclickListener(){
 public void onClick(View v){

  // if the current background == R.drawable.page0
      pages.setBackgroundResources(R.drawable.page2)

}
 });
```

thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont make it as simple as keeping the current background ID?

```
private int currentBgID = 0;

next.setOnClickListener(new View.onclickListener(){
   public void onClick(View v){

       if(R.drawable.page0 == currentBgID) {
           pages.setBackgroundResources(R.drawable.page2);
           currentBgID = R.drawable.page2;
       }

   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a flag and check and then change it in your button listener like

```
!trigger
```

Also you should use

```
setImageResource(R.drawable.page2);
```

or

```
setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pag2))
```